# Purpose of property copying to inheriting type

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, typescript

While playing around with the online TypeScript compiler, I've noticed that the creators chose to implement inheritance with the help of the following method (which I have made somewhat more readable):

```
var __extends = function(type, base) {
    for (var prop in base) { // why copy the properties?
        if (base.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            type[prop] = base[prop];
        }
    }
    function __() { // <- ?
        this.constructor = type;
    }
    __.prototype = base.prototype.
    type.prototype = new __();
};
```

The method is then used in the following manner:

```
var Item = (function () {
    function Item() {
    }
    return Item;
})();

var Sword = (function (base) {
    __extends (Sword, base);
    function Sword() {
        base.call(this);
    }
    return Sword;
})(Item);
```

I have a hard time understandind the implementation of the `__extends` method.
What is the purpose of manually copying all the properties from the extending type? Won't inheriting the prototype take care of that?

Is there a performance penalty when searching for properties in the prototype tree as opposed to directly copied properties?

The second part I also can't understand the purpose of. Instead of doing this:

```
function __() {
    this.constructor = type;
}
__.prototype = base.prototype.
type.prototype = new __();
```

Couldn't this simply be implemented as:

```
type.prototype = base.prototype;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. Let's break this down.

```
var __extends = function(type, base) {
    // ** Begin static-side inheritance **
    for (var prop in base) {
        if (base.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            type[prop] = base[prop];
        }
    }
    // ** End static-side inheritance **

    // ** Begin Object.create polyfill **
    function __() { // <- ?
        this.constructor = type;
    }
    __.prototype = base.prototype.
    // ** End Object.create polyfill **

    // ** Prototype setup **
    type.prototype = new __();
};
```

First up is the static-side inheritance. TypeScript's type system enforces that if some type has a static method, a derived class also has that method (or a method whose signature is a subtype of the base class method). This is useful for things like factory patterns, e.g.:

```
class Car {
    static create(name: string, topSpeed: number): Car {
        // ...
        return new this(/* ... */);
    }
}

class RaceCar extends Car {
    // RaceCar ignores topSpeed because it goes super fast
    static create(name: string): RaceCar {
        // ...
        return new this(/* ... */);
    }   
}

class Truck extends Car {
}

function makeTestCar(t: typeof Car) {
    return t.create('test', 60);
}
var car = makeTestCar(Car); // returns an instance of Car
var raceCar = makeTestCar(RaceCar); // returns an instance of RaceCar
var truck = makeTestCar(Truck); // OK, even though Truck doesn't explicitly implement 'create'
```

Note that in the last line, the `Truck` class got its `create` method via its base class `Car`. The copying is needed because `Truck.__proto__` is *not* `Car`.

Next up we have the `Object.create` polyfill. It's not sufficient to write `type.prototype = base.prototype` because the `__proto__` (AKA `[[proto]]`) and `prototype` members are not the same thing. Other answers on SO have given a better rundown of prototypal inheritance so I'll defer to those.

Finally the last line sets up the prototype of the constructor so that the created object has the correct `__proto__`

Comment: Looking at the answers to this question in retrospect and now that I am more experienced with TS, I feel that your answer is more complete and informative, and provides more insight. Changed to this being the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Extends copies prototype and static members (shallow copy). Statics are Parent.things and prototypes are Parent.prototype.things The way the prototype.things are copied is how the poly fill for Object create works.

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    //Copies Item.things to Sword.things
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    //Copies Item.prototype.things to Sword.prototype.things
    //this is a polyfill for Object.create
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Sword = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Sword, _super);
    function Sword() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return Sword;
})(Iten);
```

Consider the following Typescript:

```
class Item {
    public static DAMAGE = 0;
};
```

In JavaScript this will be:

```
var Item = (function () {
    function Item() {
    }
    Item.DAMAGE = 0;
    return Item;
})();
```

How would I use static DAMAGE? See the following example (simplefied JS);

```
//Using static to make general getters and setters
var Item = function(damage){ 
  this._data = [];
  this.set(Item.DAMAGE,damage)
};
Item.DAMAGE=0;
Item.prototype.get=function(dataIndex){
  return this._data[dataIndex];
};
Item.prototype.set=function(dataIndex,val){
  //maybe execute Item.rules[dataIndex].set(val) for validating value
  this._data[dataIndex] = val;
  return val;
};
var i = new Item(22);
//I could get damage using i.get(0)
//but the following reads more easily
i.get(Itesm.DAMAGE);
```

Introduction about constructor functions, prototype, inheritance, mix ins and the this value here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: As far as I can tell the missing things have no impact on my example, so that's why i removed them.

Comment: @Acidic Correct, I missed something. Created an example of how to use static and Rayan's example shows a good one for factory patterns.